# Combining two or more function using classes in PHP

Tags: php, class

I have two php classes.

```
Class classOne {

  private $stuff;
  public $stuff2;

  public function init(){
    dosomestuff;
  } 

}
```

&

```
Class classTwo extends classOne {

  private $stuff;
  public $stuff2;

  public function init(){ #This function is overriding the native classOne method init;
    dosomeotherstuff;
  } 

}
```

When i call the function init

```
$obj = new classTwo();
$obj -> init(); #dosomeotherstuff
```

The PHP interpreter will **dosomeotherstuff** as anyone would expect, because the classTwo class declared an override on the method init;

Instead, is there a way to combine the effect of the first init and the second, to obtain something like this?

```
$obj = new classTwo();
$obj -> init(); #dosomestuff, #dosomeotherstuff
```

Thanks very much

Comment: just you have to call the init methode of the parent ( parent::init(); ) in the seconde classe init method

Comment: Honestly, [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php). Please... do your homework. You're [asked to do some research](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) after all. PS: The correct term is method _overriding_, _overloading_ is something else entirely

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem my apologize, you'll notice i've used the right term in the other section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the overridden function you can call the base function:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();
    // your normal code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use parent into childre method:

```
Class classTwo extends classOne {

  private $stuff;
  public $stuff2;

  public function init(){ #This function is overloading the native classOne method init;
    parent::init();
    dosomeotherstuff;
  } 

}
```